# Vue.js strange error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set a data object called `types` when I receive a response in the `ready()` method.

Like this:

```
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      types: null
    }
  }, 

  ready () {
   TypeService.showAll(1)
      .then(function(data) {
          this.types = data.types
      });
  }
}
```

But I receive the following error in the console:

```
 Cannot set property 'types' of undefined(…)
```

But when I console.log like this:

```
 ready () {
   TypeService.showAll(1)
      .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

It's not empty!?!?

[image]

What is going on here? It drives me crazy.

--EDIT--

```
TypeService.showAll(1)  
         .then(({ data }) => ({
            this.types: data.types
          }.bind(this)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `this.types`, not `data.types` (which the JS error message doesn't make entirely clear).

```
  ready () {
   TypeService.showAll(1)
      .then(function(data) {
          this.types = data.types
      });
  }
```

`this` is not what you're expecting within the `function` here (it's not the Vue component). This should do the trick:

```
  ready () {
   TypeService.showAll(1)
      .then(function(data) {
          this.types = data.types
      }.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: @Jamie I'm not certain. The new ES6 syntax isn't something I've fully adopted yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ready () {
var _this = this
TypeService.showAll(1)
  .then(function(data) {
      _this.types = data.types
  });
}
```